# Passing token in header through variable getting an error of ParseException

Tags: cookies, header, token, karate, parseexception

Will try to be precise in asking question. Sorry if couldn't do it up to the mark!

Was given an assignment to automate api from the given below link

https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/apidoc/index.html

Using the Api chaining I am suppose to automate "Update booking" api by first generating token from  "Create Token" api and passing it in headers for authorization. I checked it on postman its working fine there for karate I wrote this code

```
* def auth_token = response.token 
Given url 'https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking/5591'
* def request_header = { Accept: '*/*' , Accept-Encoding : 'gzip, deflate, br' , Connection : 'keep-alive', Content-Type : 'application/json' , Accept : 'application/json' , Cookie : 'token=' + auth_token }
```

the variable auth_token is getting token from the first api response and under same scenario I am trying to run update api by using above headers but it keeps giving this error

```
net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token + at position 168.
```

Could not find a valid solution so dropping question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read and understand the docs, that's not how you set request headers. Here's what I think you were trying to do, and I hope that this helps others who try to use this "Restful Booker" application.

```
Feature:

Scenario:
* url 'https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com'    

* path 'auth'
* request { username: 'admin', password: 'password123' }
* method post
* status 200
* def token = response.token

* header Accept = 'application/json'
* path 'booking'
* request
"""
{
    "firstname" : "Jim",
    "lastname" : "Brown",
    "totalprice" : 111,
    "depositpaid" : true,
    "bookingdates" : {
        "checkin" : "2018-01-01",
        "checkout" : "2019-01-01"
    },
    "additionalneeds" : "Breakfast"
}    
"""
* method post
* status 200

* path 'booking', response.bookingid
* cookie token = token
* method delete
* status 201
```

Comment: Yes this solved the issue thanks for the response.